# how to unregister event log source?

Tags: delphi, winapi, events, logging, event-log

I have registered the log and added the source through the registry.
(`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<Log>\<Source>`)

When registering, the system creates evt file for the events and set up the whole log parameters.

However I don't know how could I unregister specific source or the whole Log.
I can of course delete the keys in the registry and it will dissappear from the system event viewer however the file *.evt is still blocked by the svchost and I would like to also delete this file.

How would I completely stop such a log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:
`DeregisterEventSource` Closes a write handle to the specified event log.
`ClearEventLog` Clears the specified event log, and optionally saves the current copy of the log to a backup file.

[See this MSDN Article for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363654%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the procedure is as follows:

1. install: create your registry key
2. open: `RegisterEventSource`
3. report events...
4. close: `DeregisterEventSource`
5. uninstall: delete your registry key

My point is that after successfully calling `DeregisterEventSource`, the .evt file should be deleted by the system or at least released so you should be able to delete it yourself.